# Clustering ingestion-time partitioned tables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

How should I go about clustering an ingestion-time partitioned table?
The examples mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-clustered-tables create the destination clustered table as partitioned on a column. What if I want the new clustered table to be ingestion-time partitioned as well (similar to the source)? A work around is to copy each partition separately, for example:

```
bq query --nouse_legacy_sql  --time_partitioning_type DAY --clustering_fields customer_id --destination_table='mydataset.myclusteredtable$20181001' 'SELECT * FROM `mydataset.mytable` where _PARTITIONTIME = timestamp("2018-10-01")'
```

But that's too much of a hassle.

Comment: From the docs and the link you posted: _"Currently, you can only cluster a partitioned table. This includes both ingestion-time partitioned tables and partitioned tables "_. What's the problem exactly? Are you getting an error? If so, post it please.

Comment: I have a source table that's ingestion time partitioned. I am looking for ways to convert it to a clustered table as well.